# Smooth out the outline of an object without creating more geometry

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, normals

I have this low-poly mesh:

[image]

It renders as this:

[image]

Even with Smooth Shading on, the outline is still jagged. A simple subdiv modifier fixes that, but of course it creates a lot of geometry. I feel it's very expensive to 4x or even 16x the polycount just to fix this.

Is there a way to smooth it out without changing the geometry? Does it make sense if I just bake the subdivided model's normal than use it as normal map for low-poly model? Or is there some post-processing tricks?

Comment: baking is your best bet.

Comment: I don't see how baking the high-poly will allow you to smooth the outline...

Comment: Each 'Edge' is a straight line between vertices so it is not possible to smooth the outline of a mesh without adding geometry.